# Laravel - PHP Fatal error: Class 'CreateMatchesTable' not found in migrate:refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Recently I cleaned up my tables locally, and this resulted in me deleting 'Match' table. I am now receiving errors on the production server because of this.

Locally, I ran `php artisan migrate:reset`, deleted the 'CreateMatchesTable' file and then `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`. This worked locally and I then pushed my most recent build to the server.

Now, whenever I run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` on the production server, I'm presented with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CreateMatchesTable' not found in
/home/forge/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php
on line 301
PHP Stack trace:
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
        "message":"Class 'CreateMatchesTable' not found","file":"\/home\/forge
         \/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/
         Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

I have read about other people experiencing this and I've tried `composer dump-autoload`- but the problem still persists.

Also, `php artisan dump-autoload` unfortunately presents me with this error:

```
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes

  [ErrorException]            
  Array to string conversion  

dump-autoload
```

I've deleted the site and rolled back migrations on Laravel Forge, and still, when it pulls the latest build into Forge this error occurs!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should delete the row from your `migrations` table in your database.

Comment: If you still get the issue then you should do - composer dump-autoload - as suggested by Hos Mercury (in the other answer). That worked for me

Answer (score 12):

The solution for that is

```
composer dump-autoload
```